# What is the algorithm used to encrypt Linux passwords?

Tags: passwords

I noticed during an assignment that, if I create an user with a password (`azerty` for exemple), and then call the command to change the password but give him exactly the same password:

```
passwd user
>> azerty
```

the encrypted string stored in `./etc/shadow` changes (despite the password not changing).

What algorithm is used here?

Comment: It probably depends on the OS's default choice.

Comment: I noticed that on both Ubuntu and Fedora, if that helps.

Comment: Note: It's `/etc/shadow`, not `./etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not encryption, it's a one-way hash.

There are a handful of different password hashes usually used for Linux system users' passwords, they're listed in the man page for [crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html)

The first is the original crypt algorithm, that only supported 8 character passwords (among other flaws), and which you'll hopefully never see again.

The second is the MD5-based md5crypt ([[a]](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix99/full_papers/provos/provos_html/node10.html), [[b]](http://phk.freebsd.dk/sagas/md5crypt.html)), marked with `$1$`. It's considered dated mostly because it doesn't support changing the amount of iterations, i.e. the cost of the computation.

Currently more used are the [SHA-256 and SHA-512 based hashes](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/sha-crypt.html), sha256crypt and sha512crypt, which are similar in structure to md5crypt but support variable amounts of iteration. They're marked with `$5$` and `$6$` respectively. As @SEJPM quickly enough commented, sha512crypt (`$6$`) is what at least Ubuntu and Debian currently use by default.

For `$1$`, `$5$`, and `$6$`, the characters after the identifier up to the next `$` are the salt, which is generated randomly when the password is changed.

The remaining option, not in mainline glibc is the Blowfish-based [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), marked with `$2a$` (or another letter). Bcrypt also uses a salt.

For more information on password hashing, and as to why use salts and why slower is better, see 
["How to securely hash passwords?" on security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/118457).

Comment: [Ubuntu defaults to sha512crypt.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features)

Comment: I wondered for a moment if they use sha256crypt on 32-bit platforms, since it would match the word size better. But I can't remember what was the last system I had to use that.